# Intermediate question on calculus

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable on $[-1,1]$. Assume that $f(-1)=f'(0)=0$. Show that there exists some $\xi\in (-1,1)$ such that $$f(1)=\frac{1}{3}f''(\xi).$$

I have no idea after two days' thinking...

I should say sorry that I have corrected the problem as $f'(0)=0$, no $f(0)=0$...It is not difficult for the case $f(-1)=f(0)=0$ for some intermediate value, but possibly not $1/3$.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ when you write $F$?

Comment: I'd try a power series expansion at zero, getting a coefficient, shift it to -1, getting another coefficient.  The remainder of the problem should be straightforward.

Comment: How does the right hand endpoint of the interval relate to the question ? There must be some assumption about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Consider $f(x)=x(x+1)$. This has $f''(x)=2$ and $f(1)=2$, and $2 \neq 2/3$.

Comment: there might be other zeros. If not, then you're correct +1.

Comment: @Ian I have changed the problem...I am sorry.

Comment: @VarunIyer It only takes one for a counterexample :)

Answer (score 2):

$$ (1) \ \exists c \in (-1,1): f'(c) = \frac{f(1)-f(-1)}{1-(-1)}=\frac{f(1)-0}{2} \ \ \ , (\text{Mean Value})$$

$$ (2) \ \exists d \in (-1,c): f''(d) = \frac{f'(c)-f'(-1)}{c+2} = \frac{f'(c)}{c+2} = \frac{f(1)}{2(c+2)} \Rightarrow 2(c+2)f''(d) = f(1)$$

Your prompt is not true, but if you would like to see what is true and how to use mean value, here you go. I did the second WLOG for differentiability on $(-1,c)$ or $(c,1)$. I did this so you could see the fallacy in the argument. Solve $2(c+2)= \frac{1}{3}$ and we see that our choice of "$c$" couldn't possibly lie in our domain.

Comment: I have changed the problem...I am sorry.

Comment: It's fine. Just correct the problem in the question and i can edit if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The modified prompt is also false. Consider $f(x)=x^2-1$, then $f''(x)=2$ and $f(1)=0$, and $0 \neq 2/3$.